# PHP bind_param crashes with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I'm trying my first steps with PHP and MySQL. Now I want to create a small login system and for this I want to insert a user in my database with this SQL query / PHP code:

```
include '../utils/utils.php';

if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pw']))
{       
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli(...); // Connect to database
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO User (Email, Password, Salt, Role) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $userSalt = randomString(15); // siteSalt and randomString() is stored in utils.php 
    $saltedHash = hash('sha256', $pw . $siteSalt . $userSalt);

    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $email, $saltedHash, $userSalt, 'Normal');
    if(!$stmt->execute()) die("Could not request data");

    exit; // Send 200 OK
}

header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
exit; // Send 401 Unauthorized
```

But if I run this script on my server it crashes with `500 Internal Server Error` on `bind_param(...)`.  Do you have any ideas why? I could not find my mistake. All colums are big enought and if I run the SQL query in PHP My Admin with some sample data it works great.

**EDIT:** Role is a FK but the 'Normal' value is okay for it.

Comment: this doesn't help you `if(!$stmt->execute()) die("Could not request data");` - This does `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: The script craches before `$stmt->execute()` but thanks for that. Why is that better? I thought `die(...)` would abort the whole script, right?

Comment: It will help you catch real errors should there be a db-related one. Check your logs and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. That should catch something.

Comment: Oh yes you are right thank you. The error occurs by parameter 5 so the `'Normal'` is the problem. This is a ForeignKey but on PHP My Admin it work. Do you have an idea for this?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but if you are storing hashed passwords, you should use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: @EliasNicolas Thank you for this comment. I would like to have my login as secure as possible. Some of the code comes from [here](http://subinsb.com/php-secure-login-system). Can you please have a look on it and tell me if this is the actual way to create a login system? Or is this source outdated and there are new methods to create a login?

Comment: delete psalt field in database, store the value returned from Password_hash in password field in database, and when login compare both values input and hashed password using [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) that's just for passwords.

Comment: Okay thank you I will give it a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysqli_stmt::bind_param`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) requires a variable, not a literal, for all parameters except the first one. If you first assign `'Normal'` to a variable and then pass that variable as the fifth parameter to `mysqli_stmt::bind_param`, it should work.

```
$tmp = 'Normal';
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $email, $saltedHash, $userSalt, $tmp);
```

Comment: Verify this yourself before believing me, but I believe this behaviour has been corrected in more recent versions of PHP. I suspect this because just recently I uploaded a php file from my local environment to the live environment and bind_param caused it to crash. I wasn't using a string, but this exact same solution worked for what I was using. It ran fine locally before the correction.